# How do I draw a circle with a margin surrounding a containing image?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-canvas, remoteview

I only have a RemoteViews object that contains my individual views.  I have the following layout for this RemoteViews object:

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:gravity="center">

<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="52dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:gravity="center">
<ImageView
        android:contentDescription="icon"
        android:id="@+id/icon"
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:src="@drawable/dog"
        />
</LinearLayout>
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/description"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

I am trying to draw a circle around the icon with some space in between; I don't want to trace the circle around the icon, I want there to be some whitespace in between(like a target sign).

I thought by specifying a radius larger than the imageview dimensions I could accomplish this, but the outer circle gets cut off at some parts; here "views" is the RemoteViews object:

```
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(),    
                R.drawable.dog);
Bitmap workingBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap);
Bitmap mutableBitmap = workingBitmap.copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, 
                       true);
Canvas canvas = new Canvas(mutableBitmap);

Paint paint = new Paint();
paint.setAntiAlias(true);
paint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
paint.setStrokeWidth(6);

int centerCoordinate = mutableBitmap.getWidth()/2;
canvas.drawCircle(centerCoordinate, centerCoordinate, 
centerCoordinate+15, paint);

// equivalent to imageView.setImageBitmap
views.setImageViewBitmap(R.id.icon, mutableBitmap);
```

Answer (score 1):

Please try this modified code. I've tried explaining the changes in the comments. Sorry if they are insufficient:

```
        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(),    
                R.drawable.dog);
        //
        // vvvv Commented out vvvv
        /*
         * Reason: The new Bitmap must be larger than the bitmap around
         * which the circle must be drawn. 
         */
//        Bitmap workingBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap);
//        Bitmap mutableBitmap = workingBitmap.copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, 
//                true);
//        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(mutableBitmap);
        // ^^^^ Commented out ^^^^
        //
        // vvvv Added vvvv
        // This is the total (Right + left) extra space on the sides;
        int padding = 30;
        // Since the Paint is going to draw a noticeably thick line, the thickness must be included in the calculations
        int strokeWidth = 6;
        /*
         * Calculating single dimension since the bitmap must have a square shape for the circle to fit.
         * Also account for the padding and the stroke width;
         */
        int bitmapSize = Math.max(bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight()) + padding + strokeWidth;
        Bitmap workingBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmapSize, bitmapSize,
                Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(workingBitmap);
        // ^^^^ Added ^^^^
        //
        Paint paint = new Paint();
        paint.setAntiAlias(true);
        paint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        //
        // paint.setStrokeWidth(6);
        paint.setStrokeWidth(strokeWidth);
        //
        // canvas.drawCircle(centerCoordinate, centerCoordinate, 
        //         centerCoordinate+15, paint);
        /*
         * Calculate exact top left position in the result Bitmap to draw the original Bitmap
         */
        canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, (bitmapSize - bitmap.getWidth()) / 2.0f,
                (bitmapSize - bitmap.getHeight()) / 2.0f, paint);
        //
        // int centerCoordinate = mutableBitmap.getWidth()/2;
        int centerCoordinate = bitmapSize / 2;
        //
        //canvas.drawCircle(centerCoordinate, centerCoordinate, 
        // centerCoordinate+15, paint);
        /*
         * Draw the circle but account for the stroke width of the paint or else the circle will flatten on the edges of the Bitmap.
         */
        canvas.drawCircle(centerCoordinate, centerCoordinate,
                centerCoordinate - (strokeWidth/2.0f), paint);
        // equivalent to imageView.setImageBitmap
        // views.setImageViewBitmap(R.id.icon, mutableBitmap);
        views.setImageViewBitmap(R.id.icon, workingBitmap);
```

Also in the layout for the `ImageView` add:

`android:scaleType="fitXY"`

Edit:
To keep the inner bitmap size fixed and only vary the circle size, first, the `ImageView` and its `LinearLayout` container **cannot** have a fixed size. Change all of those layout width and height values in the layout to `"wrap_content"`.

Secondly since the image resource for `"bitmap"` is of an unknown size, `bitmap` will have to be loaded with a scaled down version of the resource that fits the **maximum allowable dimension** for the bitmap **only**, which in your case is **30px**. This can be done by replacing:

```
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(),    
                    R.drawable.dog);
```

With the following code:

```
//
// Value to hold the required image dimension;
int requiredImageDimension = 30;
// Decode the Bitmap resource with the set options.
Bitmap originalBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
        R.drawable.dog);
// Scaled bitmap reference;
Bitmap bitmap = null;
// Check if the largest dimension is the width;
if (originalBitmap.getWidth() > originalBitmap.getHeight()) {
    // Force the width to the maximum allowable size and calculate
    // the scaled height of the Bitmap;
    bitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(originalBitmap,
            requiredImageDimension,
            originalBitmap.getHeight() * requiredImageDimension
                    / originalBitmap.getWidth(), true);
}
// If the width and height are equal;
else if(originalBitmap.getWidth() == originalBitmap.getHeight()){
    // Force the width and height to the maximum allowable size;
    bitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(originalBitmap,
            requiredImageDimension,
            requiredImageDimension, true);
}
// If the largest dimension is the height;
else {
    // Force the height to the maximum allowable size and calculate
    // the scaled width of the Bitmap;
    bitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(originalBitmap,
            originalBitmap.getWidth() * requiredImageDimension
                    / originalBitmap.getHeight(),
            requiredImageDimension, true);
}
```

So now you get a scaled down version of the **original** bitmap resource which will be pasted on the larger `workingBitmap` and loaded into the `ImageView` which will resize itself to accommodate the bitmap without scaling.

Comment: Thanks, the circle no longer gets cut off but the padding is very minimal.  Increasing it has no effect.  In the xml above I had to set specific dimensions for the bitmap since it was too big.  How do I increase the padding around my icon?

Comment: In this code if you increase "`padding`" (I tried doubling it), the `Bitmap` object size (dimension) **will** increase but your icon in the `ImageView` will look smaller. That is because the large image is forced to the `ImageView`s size. If you want your **icon** to have the same (physical) size while **increasing** the size of the **circle**, then you are going to have to allow the `ImageView` to scale itself based on the `Bitmap` size, **i.e.** it **cannot** have a fixed width. Do you want **that**?...

Comment: Thanks.  Yes, I want the icon to stay 30x32 and increase the radius of my circle without having it cut off.